# get a value from url - jsp

Tags: jsp, getparameter

> hello! I have this url www.someurl.jsp?param=1 and i want to store the
>   1 into a variable
>
> > i wrote this

```
<% int r=request.getParameter("param");%>
```

> and i have an error "incompatible types ,required:int, found:String" i
>   wrote then this

```
<% int r= (int) request.getParameter("param");%>
```

> but it doesnt work also...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.getParameter("param")` will return String.So you need to convert it to int.For that you need to do typecasting

like

```
<% int r=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("param"));%>
```

Comment: Hey, I gave this exact same code first, 3 min before he did :-) Oh well, I'm glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use parseInt

```
<% int r=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("param"));%>
```

Comment: +1 your answer is also same.but i gave some explanation.So i gave u +1